# Display HTML Select box Based on Selecting Option From Other Select box Noob Question

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2

Trying to get innerHTML to display select box when an option of another select box is chosen.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script> // In your Javascript (external .js resource or <script> tag)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cars2").select2();
});
</script>
<!--Need help here-->
<script>
function myFunction(event){
 var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
 //here you are picking the selected option item
 var y = $('select#cars2 option:selected').val();
 switch (y) {
  case '1':
    x.innerHTML = "<label for="carsyo">Choose a yingyang</label>

<select name="cars3" id="cars4">
  <option value="volvo">Voldo</option>
  <option value="saab">Roy drives</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>";
    break;
  case '2':
    x.innerHTML = "<p>Roy!</p>";
  }
}
</script>

<style>
select {
width: 150px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDIV"><p>
Hello
</p></div>

<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select id="cars2" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="0">Pick something</option>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Opel</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/CoolBuys1290/59qmbt0f/28/

Web page doesn't do anything. I have to add extra text for some reason.

Please help a noob out.

Thanks

Comment: You can't have a line break in a string, so the assignment to `x.innerHTML` causes a syntax error. Didn't you see that in the console?

Comment: All I see is unexpected identifier carsyo in JSFiddle. How am I supposed to display the select box when a case is matched? Just remove all line breaks?

Comment: Another problem is that you're using double quote as the string delimiter and also as the delimiter around the attributes in the HTML. If you use the same delimiter in both places, you need to escape the inner quotes. But see the answer below for a solution to both problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 20-27, you have a multiline string with `"` quotes. You can't create multine strings using `"` in JS without adding `\` to the end of each line. So simply replace the `"` with `` ` `` where you need to create a multi-line string like this: `` x.innerHTML = `<label for="carsyo">Choose a yingyang</label> ``

The better option would be to include the second select directly in your HTML and [show/hide it like this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp).